# Optimize SELECT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Would it be possible to reform the following query (2 simple tables linked by column ITEM_ID), which takes > 4 seconds (SQL CE) to return 17500 lines (ITEM = 90000 lines, ITEMSTATS = 190000 lines):

```
select COUNT(a.ITEM_ID) 
from ITEM a 
where  EXISTS (SELECT ITEM_ID 
               FROM ITEMSTATS
               WHERE ITEM_ID = a.ITEM_ID 
                 AND STAT_ID = 12
                 AND TYPE = 0
                 AND cast(VALUE as integer) >= 0)
```

I created an index on
[ITEMSTATS] ([ITEM_ID], [STAT_ID], [TYPE]) 
(if I add [VALUE], it doesn't change anything)
and
[ITEM_ID] is the PK of [ITEM]

Thanks.

Comment: Datatype for VALUE column?

Comment: I think you should be able to JOIN both tables based on the item id and get rid of the subselect.

Comment: If JOIN, do SELECT DISTINCT on ITEMSTATS before joining.

Comment: VALUE is a NVARCHAR(12), with values like "+1", "+100", .. 
I made a test by removing it from the EXISTS, no change...

Comment: Well,  I tried with INNER JOIN ITEMSTATS... and there is no noticeable difference. I think I will stay with that...

Comment: Try an index on `(stat_id, type, item_id) include (value)`

Comment: You could also use the query `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) FROM itemstats WHERE stat_id = 12 AND type = 0 AND cast(value AS integer) >= 0 ;` No need for the join if there is an FK that can be trusted.

Comment: And why, oh why, is the column a NVARCHAR when it is storing integers? The best (not only for this query) would be to convert it.

Comment: About VALUE, there are also some values like "+25%" (for TYPE != 0), so I cannot convert it to INT...

Comment: About  "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT...",  It is not allowed (SQL CE) and must be set as subselect

Comment: 25%  is a percentage but still a number (25/100 = 0.25). But it seems you are storing different "types" of numbers (absolute and percents) in the same column which isn't good.

Comment: No,  I must keep "+n%" like this because it is concatened later in a string as information text.

Comment: Could you not use two `int` columns, one for an absolute value and the other for per cent, and later concatenate conditionally either one or the other?

Comment: And by the way, if you want to make sure the person you are replying to is notified of your reply, address them [using the "@" and their username](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) (like this: @ypercube).